# Syntax error in httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.so: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I was trying to compile mod_wsgi for my Python 2.7 found in virtual env. My sever default is 2.6.6.

So I ran this on the mod_wsgi source:

```
./configure --with-python=/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7 \    LDFLAGS="-R/usr/local/lib"
```

Then

```
make && make install
```

And after doing that, when I try to start httpd, I get this error:

```
Syntax error on line 202 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Check out http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/.  In short, you need to compile Python as a shared library in order for mod_wsgi to work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if "mod_wsgi.so" is inside "/etc/httpd/modules/"?

If it is in there, try changing "/etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so" to "modules/mod_wsgi.so"

Comment: Yes it is and it's already referred to as `"modules/mod_wsgi.so"`